# How to prevent new lines in a textarea with a maxlength

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a textbox with a maximum of 3 visible rows of text each one with a max of characters depending on the width of the textarea.

This is what I tried:

```
<textarea class="form-control" cols="33" wrap="hard" maxlength="100" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

This allows me to have three lines and because of the wrap hard it breaks the text into the next line with no problem. Except if you add an Enter,
you can have more than 3 visible lines.

Is there a way to prevent this and be aware on where the text has broken into next lines?

This is something I tried avoiding the maxlength attribute:

```
textboxElement.addEventListener('keypress keyup', function (event) {
        var text, lines, currentLine, currentText, hasSelectedAllText,
        textComponent, selectedText, sel, startPos,endPos;

        text = textboxElement.textboxElement.val();
        lines = text.split("\n");
        currentLine = this.value.substr(0, this.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
        currentText = textboxElement.getValues();
        textComponent = textboxElement;

        if (document.selection != undefined) {
            textboxElement.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            selectedText = sel.text;
            if (selectedText) {
              hasSelectedAllText = true;
            }
        } else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
            startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
            endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
            selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
            if (selectedText) {
              hasSelectedAllText = true;
            }
        }


        if (lines.length >= $(this).attr('rows') && lines[currentLine - 1].length >= $(this).attr('cols')) {
          if (/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)) && !hasSelectedAllText) { 
            var text = textboxElement.getValues();
             textboxElement.setValues(text.substring(0, text.length - 2));
          }
        } else if (lines[currentLine - 1].length >= $(this).attr('cols')) {
          textboxElement.val(text + "\n");
        }

      });
```

The problem with this is that this adds those `\n` and it's hard to delete content because sometimes it gets bugged. You can't modify a word that you already wrote. It breaks words instead of pushing them to the next line. 
So basically with my manual implementation I broke the textarea.

All I want is to avoid the user to see more than 3 visible lines to type.

Comment: But why? This sounds like a form input with poor usability and accessibility.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear an answer to @jedifans question. Because limiting the textarea to 3 visible rows and a maxlength sounds like a solution to a problem that may be able to be solved another way.

Comment: i was asked to do this, this is basically from my perspective only to make an ui im working with "look better" and by that i mean it would only give you the feel of having 3 lines (which is what fits into this UI) with a max length per line equally to what fits in the textarea width

Comment: Use the attribute rows. `<textarea rows="3" ...`!

Comment: i already did that, it just does not work, you can click enter and it will go to a new line

Answer (score 0):

This Should work.
Tested on codepen, COpied and pasted long text, hit enter rows are fixed.

```css
textarea {
 width: 300px;
 max-height: 50px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" wrap="hard" maxlength="100" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

style="resize:none;">